# React Query / RTK Query integration with Redux?

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit, react-query, rtk-query

I'm running a comparison between RTK Query and React Query, trying to decide which one to use in my React/Redux app.

One of the points for consideration is their integration with Redux.

I did some research and it seems like the only difference between the two in that regard, is that if using RTK Query you would see the query results in your Redux store and in the Redux DevTools which is a bit more convenient.

Am i missing something else? Or other than that, they both work the same with Redux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RTK Query is part of your Redux store and as such also internally works with Redux. Everything is an action. So you can listen for those actions in your own middlewares or you can have your normal slice reducers act on top of those actions.

Granted, both React Query and RTK Query take over cache management for you, so in both cases, that data will be kinda separated - just because it is conceptually not very interwoven with your other state in most situations.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate more on the "everything is an action" and "you can listen for those actions in your own middleware" parts?
Does that mean that every action RTK Query executes (caching, polling, refetching, etc..) is being dispatched as a Redux action that you can listen to and act on using different middleware such as Redux Saga?

Comment: I'd recommend taking a look in the Redux Devtools to see what is being dispatched. The most common actions to watch for are probably the fulfilled/rejected/pending actions for the endpoints. You can use [these matchers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#matchers) for them.

Comment: Ok got it, thank you!

Comment: @Gambit2007 What was your conclusion to this topic? I am also debating using React Query vs RTK Query for a React and RTK app. The only thing stopping me from using RTK Query even if I have RTK installed is because it's labeled experimental. React Query seems to have a lot more development and support behind it, even though they do the same thing essentially. 

If you find the integration w redux was helpful? React Query has its own dev tools

Comment: @pancake author of RTK Query here. It is not labeled as experimental, we released half a year ago. What makes you think it is experimental?

Comment: @phry My mistake I was reading an article from earlier this year that said it was a new experimental library which I realize is quite a while ago

Answer (score 0):

If redux is being used then RTK query can be a good choice for cache management because then the reducer of the api services **example:** post service, can be easily used in the store by adding them in the reducer object in the store. And if RTK query will be used with redux then there will be a lesser requirement of writing middleware in the code for redux.